# Installer hangs during installation at "select location" screen

Tags: installation, freeze, location

I never seem to be able to get a Linux distro to install. Now I'm trying Ubuntu and running into a problem.

I installed via VirtualBox first and it worked fine.

The installer from the boot disk starts up fine. It created the partition (dual boot with Windows 7), copies the files, and that's it.  It sits there doing nothing.

At this point I am on the screen where it asks me to choose my location, and all I get is a spinning cursor telling me it's trying to do something, but it doesn't really do anything even after 10 minutes of waiting.

System:

```
Intel I3-2100
8GB DDR3 Ram
120GB SSD main drive + 3 1TB sata
Windows 7
Nvidia GT650 Video card
```

I'm using the Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit image.

Answer (score 2):

A friend gave me a hand with this, and it appears that because I have an odd mouse (Cyborg RAT 3) it does not play well with any distro.

The solution just in case anyone finds themselves in this position is below, this also explains why I could not install 12.0.4 LTS as the mouse button was ignoring my clicks.

If you press the profile button on the mouse left click will start working once or twice then you need to press it again to get the left click back and so on.

Anyway to fix this, only works for the RAT3 Mouse do the following and reboot.

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

then paste this at the end;

```
# RAT3 mouse
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Mouse Remap"
MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.3 Mouse"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 0 0 0 13 14"
EndSection
```